# WPF Custom Expander button style not responding properly to mouse clicks

Tags: wpf, styling

i have he following expander toggle button style, that is visually getting closer to what I want but it does not respond properly clicks.  When you click on it to expand or collapse, it does not always respond.  Any ideas?  TIA.

> ```
>        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderToggleButton"
>          TargetType="ToggleButton">
>             <Canvas Width="14" Height="14">
>                 <Rectangle Stroke="Gray"  
>                            RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" 
>                            StrokeThickness="1"  Width="14" Height="14" 
>                            Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top ="0"/>
>                 <Path RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" 
>                           Name="ExpandPath" 
>                           Stroke="Black" 
>                           Margin="0" 
>                           StrokeThickness="1" 
>                           Data="M 5 1 L 5 9 M 1 5 L 9 5" 
>                       Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top ="2"/>            
>             </Canvas>
>             <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>                 <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
>                     <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="ExpandPath"
>                               Value="M 1 5 L 9 5"/>
>                 </Trigger>                   
>             </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>         </ControlTemplate>
>         <!-- Expander style -->
>         <Style TargetType="Expander">                
>             <Setter Property="Template">
>                 <Setter.Value>
>                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="Expander">
>                         <Grid>
>                             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
>                                 <RowDefinition Name="ContentRow" Height="0"/>
>                             </Grid.RowDefinitions>                              
>                             <Border 
>                                 Name="Border" 
>                                 Grid.Row="0"                                    
>                                 BorderThickness="1" 
>                                 CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" >
>                                 <Grid>
>                                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
>                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
>                                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                                     <ToggleButton
>                                         Grid.Column="0"
>                                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, 
>                                                             Mode=TwoWay,
>                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource
>                                                             TemplatedParent}}"
>                                         OverridesDefaultStyle="True" 
>                                         Template="{StaticResource 
>                                                  ExpanderToggleButton}" />
>                                     <ContentPresenter 
>                                         Grid.Column="1"
>                                         Margin="4" 
>                                         ContentSource="Header" 
>                                         RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
>                                 </Grid>
>                             </Border>
>                             <Border 
>                                 Name="Content" 
>                                 Grid.Row="1"                                    
>                                 BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" 
>                                 CornerRadius="0,0,4,4" >
>                                 <ContentPresenter Margin="4" />
>                             </Border>
>                         </Grid>
>                         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>                             <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
>                                 <Setter TargetName="ContentRow" Property="Height"
>                                         Value="{Binding 
>                                         ElementName=Content,Path=DesiredHeight}" />
>                             </Trigger>                             
>                         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>                     </ControlTemplate>
>                 </Setter.Value>
>             </Setter>
>         </Style>
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the background of the `Canvas` in the `ControlTemplate` to "Transparent":

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderToggleButton"
    TargetType="ToggleButton">

    <!-- The canvas needs a background to work properly with clicks,
         so set it to Transparent -->
    <Canvas Width="14" Height="14" Background="Transparent">
        <Rectangle Stroke="Gray"  
                    RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" 
                    StrokeThickness="1"  Width="14" Height="14" 
                    Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top ="0"/>
        <Path RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" 
                    Name="ExpandPath" 
                    Stroke="Black" 
                    Margin="0" 
                    StrokeThickness="1" 
                    Data="M 5 1 L 5 9 M 1 5 L 9 5" 
                Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top ="2"/>
    </Canvas>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="ExpandPath"
                        Value="M 1 5 L 9 5"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When there is no canvas background you have to click exactly on the path (the + or the -) to get the click to register. With the canvas background you can click anywhere on the canvas.

Comment: Glad that I could help! I've had the same problem myself :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue sometimes happens when a scrollviewer is involved.

Try adding this setter:

```
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False" />
```